# Why is EF performing this UPDATE statement if it only sets a variable?

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I'm using EF 6.0.1. I've seens this SQL come out while doing `SaveChanges()` on some data:

```
-- this is generated by EF, according to IntelliTrace:
DECLARE @p int
UPDATE [dbo].[GlobalIds]
SET @p = 0
WHERE ([Id] = @0)
SELECT [UniqueId]
FROM [dbo].[GlobalIds]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = @0
```

MyTable is a table (duh) that has an int PK called `Id`, and `UniqueId` is just a column (`UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, if it makes any difference).

1. What's the point of this query? `@p` is a local variable in the context of the query - why does it need to be updated to have the same value as the @0 parameter?
2. Why do we need `@@ROWCOUNT > 0` in the where clause?

This query looks equivalent to just selecting `UniqueId`:

```
SELECT [UniqueId]
FROM [dbo].[GlobalIds]
WHERE [Id] = @0
```

**Edit**: I know EF doesn't output optimal queries. I'm trying to gain some insight as to why EF does this specifically.

Comment: No one ever said EF created good SQl.

Comment: @HLGEM, Right, but I'm looking for answers such as "you misunderstand the query because it does X...", or "EF does this because..."

Comment: Can you show the C#/VB code that caused this SQL to be generated?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, working on it...it's buried deep inside some framework of ours

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @p int
set @p = 0
select @@rowcount
```

That ill return 1 row!

The only insight maybe you missed is EF performance (no it's not a joke).
It happens if there's no match for

```
WHERE ([Id] = @0)
```

update ill set @@rowcount to zero
and the

```
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = @0
```

ill not bother seeking for that id because @@ROWCOUNT > 0 == false

Comment: The alternative query `SELECT .. WHERE Id = @0` is just as fast as an update with `WHERE`. I don't see the need to split it into two steps (if anything, it will confuse SQL Server's plan cache and optimizer)

Comment: Fast as? It depends. If EF is doing dumb things instead of best way, sure. Why it does it this way? You ill need to ask EF developers. All I can say it behaves like it want to be sure of that update can take place and if it don't happens don't bother with the select.